# Calculation for how many of X is in Y and the remainder

Tags: php

Is there a better way of doing this in php - I'd have thought so but this is all I can think of.

```
$x = 4
$y = 32

while ($y > $x) { $y = $y-$x; }
```

The final value of $y is what I'm after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the mod operator:

```
$remainder = $y % $x;
```

If you want to get how many, use division and take the floor:

```
$total = floor( $y / $x);
```

So, with `$y = 35;` and `$x = 4;`, you'd get:

```
$total = 8, $remainder = 3
```

Comment: DOH! Yeah - I KNEW there was an easier way to do this as I'd done it before. Thanks for the memory jog!

Comment: Just remember that modulus in php only works for integers...  If your values are ever floating point, you'll need to use fmod instead.